# Problem with colors of camstudio recorded video

Tags: video-recording

I am using windows 7 and try to capture a video of my screen using camstudio 2.7. I am using camstudio lossless codec v1.5. The problem is that colors in my recorded video are inverted somehow. For example blue color is red. How I can repair this. I want just normal screen video.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the recording setting, maybe a non-standard color space is being used or the video is simply being interpreted falsely by your video player.
Try to play it with a different player.

If thats not the issue you should double check the record setting you are using for this codec or maybe change the codec you are recording with.